# Cordova Embedding Webview transparent on native app

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I followed the "Embedding Cordova WebView" guide to make cordova work with my native app, and thats works fine ...

But it could be nice if the cordova webview could be transparent as an overlay on my native app..

Anyone know if this is posible?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming everything is on the same layout behind the appview it's an easy thing to make the WebView transparent.

You can easily set the alpha of the appView variable:

```
appView.setAlpha(0.5f);
```

If everything is not in the same layout you need to provide more details on what exactly you're trying to achieve here.